# I have an API that runs through an array and I want to send data to the client on each array element

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, send

I have an API that runs through an array and I want so send data to the client on each array element, i have tried using res.write with res.flush but it still waits until the end to send everything, is there a way that the data can be sent by chunks?

```
for (let i = 0; i < searchUrl.length; i++) {
      const element = searchUrl[i];
      const element_details = await getDetailsforURL(element)
      res.write(JSON.stringify(element_details))
      res.flush()
      //return_array.push(element_details)
    }
    res.end()
```

Comment: Why would you send on each elements on your array ? Send the array and handle that in your front

Comment: `write` function is part of `net` module?

Comment: i have tried that handling the array on the front end already. the problem is with handling of errors, once an error happens it crashes the whole page. so I thought it would be better to handle the whole data on the back end and just send the results to the front  end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.write()` adds content to the body of the response. Basically with every `res.write()` you add data to the body and send it with `res.end()`. If you want to send it in chunks you need one request per chunk, meaning that the client needs to continuously send requests until all data is received.

If you don't want to send the whole array, you could do the processing on the server side and send the result to the client:

```
let response = [];
for (let i = 0; i < searchUrl.length; i++)
    const element = searchUrl[i];
    const element_details = await getDetailsforURL(element);
    response.push(element_details);
    
}
res.write(JSON.stringify(element_details));
res.end();
```